# From array to menu

Tags: routes

How can I render an array as a menu? Is there some core function I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if your array has the structure of a menu array. See the output of

```
$tree = menu_tree_page_data('main-menu');
```

for a reference of a valid menu array structure.

Once you have your array, this is how you can render it.

```
$main_menu = menu_tree_output($tree);
print drupal_render($main_menu);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [theme_links()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_links/7).

```
$links = array(
  'item1' => array('title' => '1st Item', 'href' => 'one' ),
  'item2' => array('title' => '2nd Item', 'href' => 'two' ),
);

print theme('links', array(
  'links' => $links,
  'attributes' => array('class' => array('links', 'inline')))
);
```